# Parametrization of a regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

I've been trying to solve the following problem from Do Carmo's book:

Let $P = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x = y\}$ and let $\textbf{x}\colon U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be given by
\begin{equation}
\textbf{x}(u,v) = (u + v, u + v, uv),
\end{equation}
where $U = \{(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid u > v\}$. Clearly, $\textbf{x}(U) \subset P$. Is $\textbf{x}$ a parametrization of $P$?

If this is the case, then this transformation should be a homeomorphism. So, I tried to find a topological invariant such as connectedness, and prove that the image did not satisfy the invariant. However, apparently, this transformation is a homeomorphism. Please if you can help me out with this, I will really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to look to the derivative of $X$, it doesn't satisfy the regularity condition on some points.

Comment: I will check that. Thanks!

Comment: @TheGiraffeGuy, the function $\textbf{x}$ satisfies the regularity condition. Notice that the Jacobian matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\\ v & u \end{pmatrix}$, and the nullspace of this matrix is the zero vector unless $ u = v$ which is impossible since $u \neq v$ for elements in $U$.

Comment: O sorry, I didn't pay attention to $U$, in this case it does satisfy that condition. Then maybe it is a parametrization of $P$, or do you know that it's not?

Comment: Probably it is a parametrization, but I don't think so. Anyway, I'll try to prove it is a parametrization to see what goes wrong. Thanks!